# Programmatic configuration of HTTPService with ServletListener and Filter

Tags: java, servlets, osgi, shiro, servletcontextlistener

I try to implement a HttpService in an OSGI environment in combination with VAADIN and shiro. So i declared the following BundleActivator:

```
import java.util.logging.Level;

import org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.ExtendedHttpService;

import org.osgi.framework.BundleContext;
import org.osgi.framework.BundleEvent;
import org.osgi.framework.ServiceReference;
import org.osgi.service.http.HttpContext;
import org.osgi.util.tracker.ServiceTracker;
import org.osgi.util.tracker.ServiceTrackerCustomizer;

/**
 *
 * @author nspecht
 */
public class BundleActivator extends some.package.BundleActivator implements ServiceTrackerCustomizer
{

/**
 * Service tracker.
 */
private ServiceTracker tracker;

/**
 * HttpService.
 */
private ExtendedHttpService httpService;

@Override
protected void afterStart(BundleContext bc, DependencyManager dm) {
    this.tracker = new ServiceTracker(this.context, ExtendedHttpService.class, this);
    this.tracker.open();
}

@Override
protected void beforeStop(BundleContext bc, DependencyManager dm) {
    if (this.tracker != null) {
        this.tracker.close();
        this.tracker = null;
    }
}

@Override
protected void afterBundleChanged(BundleEvent be) {

}

@Override
public Object addingService(ServiceReference sr) {
    this.httpService = (ExtendedHttpService)this.context.getService(sr);
    HttpContext httpContext = this.httpService.createDefaultHttpContext();
    try {

        MainServlet mainServlet = new MainServlet();
        this.httpService.registerServlet(MainServlet.PATH, mainServlet, null, httpContext);

        // TODO: add ServletContextListener and Filter

        LoginServlet loginServlet = new LoginServlet();
        this.httpService.registerServlet(LoginServlet.PATH, loginServlet, null, httpContext);

        // TODO: add ServletContextListener and Filter

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(BundleActivator.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    return this.httpService;
}

@Override
public void modifiedService(ServiceReference sr, Object t) {
}

@Override
public void removedService(ServiceReference sr, Object t) {
    this.httpService.unregister(MainServlet.PATH);
    this.httpService.unregister(LoginServlet.PATH);
    // TODO: remove ServletContextListener and Filter
}
}
```

MyServlets are VaadinServlets. Now i want to add Shiro to my application. To make shiro work correctly i have to add the EnvironmentLoaderListemer and ShiroFilter to my services.

If I try the following:

```
mainServlet.mainServlet.getServletContext().addListener(...)
```

the application crashes (because context has already been initialized).

```
mainServlet.getServletContext().createListener(...)
```

does not throw an exception but the ServletContextListener does not work either.
The httpService does not have a method to add Listeners that way.
Filters have the same problem and the httpService.registerFilter(...) method is useless with a ShiroFilter when there is no EnvironmentLoader registered by the Listener.

Are there workarounds to add Shiro the programmatic way?

Is there a way to add Listeners and Filters for my Servlets?

Comment: You can't add listeners with the `ExtendedHttpService` interface?

Comment: No i can't. There are methods for adding servlets, resources and filters only. Thats it. Or are you using a different version/package?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally i found a solution. I created my own ShiroFilter and added it as usual to my httpService:

```
ServletFilter filter = new ServletFilter();
this.httpService.registerFilter("/", filter, null, httpContext);
```

The ServletFilter is also simple:

```
public class ServletFilter extends IniShiroFilter
{
    @Override
    protected Ini loadIniFromConfig() {
        return new MyIni();
    }

    @Override
    protected Ini loadIniFromPath() {
        return this.loadIniFromConfig();
    }
}
```

And finally the MyIni class:

```
public class MyIni extends Ini
{
/**
 * Constructor.
 */
public MyIni() {
    super();
    // Set a class loader, which is able to resolve your classes!
    Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(new BundleWideClassLoader());
    this.config();

}

@Override
public String toString() {
    StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder();
    buf.append("# ").append(this.getClass().getCanonicalName()).append("\n");

    for (String section : this.getSectionNames()) {
        buf.append("\n[").append(section).append("]\n");
        Section s = this.getSection(section);
        for (String key : s.keySet()) {
            buf.append(key).append(" = ").append(s.get(key)).append("\n");
        }
    }

    return buf.toString();
}

@Override
public void load(InputStream iniConfig) {
    // do nothing
}

@Override
public void load(Scanner scanner) {
    //do nothing
}

/**
 * Configure this ini.
 */
private void config() {
    Section main = this.addSection("main");
    main.put("authc.loginUrl", "/login");
    main.put("authc.successUrl", "/");
    main.put("authc.usernameParam", "user");
    main.put("authc.passwordParam", "pass");
    main.put("authc.rememberMeParam", "remember");

    main.put("ds", com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource.class.getCanonicalName());
    ...

    main.put("matcher", org.apache.shiro.authc.credential.HashedCredentialsMatcher.class.getCanonicalName());
    main.put("matcher.hashAlgorithmName", "SHA-256");

    main.put("jdbcRealm", org.apache.shiro.realm.jdbc.JdbcRealm.class.getCanonicalName());
    ...

    main.put("jdbcRealm.dataSource", "$ds");
    main.put("jdbcRealm.credentialsMatcher", "$matcher");
    main.put("securityManager.realms", "$jdbcRealm");

    Section urls = this.addSection("urls");
    urls.put("/VAADIN/**", "anon");
    urls.put("/login/**", "anon");
    urls.put("/login", "authc");
    urls.put("/**", "authc");
}
}
```